# How to fix / Reset App Store app on Mac OSX - El Capitan

Tags: macos

Newly upgraded to Latest released OS X - El Capitan (10.11.5). Now when I open App Store app, the spinning wheel to right of < > buttons on upper left side continues to spin with no content visible below on any tab button. Originally, I saw that 1-update was available. I read an earlier note to use Activity Monitor and kill processes related to App Store. Saw 2 that had long process times (storeassetd, storedownloadd). Plus now see App Store Web Content in "(not responding state). How do I fix this???

Answer (score 27):

- Go to Finder and press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>;
- Locate `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore` and delete `com.apple.appstore` which are cache files;
- Then press again those commands and go `/private/var/folders`, open each folder and each subfolder until you find `com.apple.appstore` and delete this folder;
- Restart your Mac.

Comment: No such ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore directory exists.
Nor does (terminal) /private/var/folders/ contain anything related to
"com.apple.appstore". Will restart in a few minutes. Maybe this will correct things.

Comment: Did all this. Doesn't seem to make a diff. No tab displays any content. Yet I was told a update was available. I selected Install. It went of to do something. Don't know what.

Comment: Am I forced to reinstall???

Comment: Strange, they exist on my Mac. Ah, go only to `~/Library/Caches/` and find folders the `com.apple.appstore`, `storeaccount`, `storeassets`, `storedownload` and `storeinapp`. Delete these folders. Then go again to `/private/var/folders/`. At `/private/var/folders/`, there are two subfolders, go to the first subfolder and then go to that folder and after to the folder C that cointains the folder `com.apple.appstore`.

Comment: I contacted Apple. They told me to delete the whole Caches folder at the location you mentioned. Cause a bunch of problems that just got resolved and a lot of time and a couple reboots. Its working now. Maybe I'll follow your suggestions to the letter from now on.

Comment: This tip solved the problem for me on macOS Mojave 10.14.2, too.

The directories were somewhat different, though, but just delete everything that has something to do with `appstore` under `~/Library/Caches/`

Comment: Combined all these and it finally seemed to do the trick. `sudo find /private/var/folders/ -iname 'com.apple.appstore' 2>/dev/null | while IFS='' read -r line; do rm -fr "$line"; done; rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/*store*; ps aux | egrep -i 'app.?store' | awk '{ print $2 }' | while IFS='' read -r line; do kill -9 "$line"; done` Stupid, stupid, stupid-stupid-stupid software.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik Not even that command worked for me :(

Comment: Might need to just bite the bullet and reinstall the OS from recovery boot, then. It should leave your personal data intact (but make a full backup first if you're paranoid).

Answer (score 9):

For me, the command that resolved this was:

```
sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog
```

(Found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/221419/238906)

Comment: Bear in mind, is for resetting the System Updates url for macOS. The OP is asking about App Store. Two different things.

Comment: This option is deprecated in Catalina (10.15.4, 19E287).

Answer (score 4):

After hours of trying different ways of re-installing an app from the App Store (deleting the app in Launchpad, enabling app store debug menu and resetting application, rebooting, etc) the only thing that worked for me was **deleting** the following folders and **rebooting**:

```
~/Library/Caches/storeaccount
~/Library/Caches/storeassets
~/Library/Caches/storedownload
~/Library/Caches/storeinappd
```

After this I was finally able to see an "Install" button next to the app I deleted rather than an "Open" button. In addition, 5 other apps I had deleted were originally showing under the Updates tab as having updates. After deleting the above 4 folders, those apps were no longer showing up under the Updates tab.

I think it's absolutely ridiculous that there isn't an easier way to re-download/re-install an app from the App Store.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried all of this. What I have done is delete the App Store key chain entry in Finder, Application, Utilities, Keychain Access and then search for appstore. Delete just that one. (MacOS Catalina).

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how to achieve this? None of the previously mentioned solutions work in Catalina. Thanks

Comment: Hi Chris! I just done that. First go to Finder, then Application and so on as my answer described. Please, follow that and let me know.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I am just not sure what exactly I should be deleting. Can you please be more specific in what files I need to delete, thanks!

Comment: Chris, there you will find lot of entries, like a list of items. One of them may be called appstore or similar. Delete just that. I cannot be more specific because it is just that. Perhaps you don't have that item (or file). Hope you find it!