# Ghost Updates on Mac

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update, dock, macos

My dock tells me I have 8 available updates:

[image: app store]

I also got the notification asking to install updates. However, when I open App Store, I only see recently installed updates (with no updates to apps or software visible):

[image: updates installed]

If the updates are real, how do I update, and if not, how do I get rid of the bubble?

**Edit** (more information):

```
$ defaults read com.apple.appstore
{
    "NSWindow Frame Preferences" = "0 116 1277 661 0 0 1280 777 ";
    "NSWindow Frame window_prefs" = "20 51 1240 726 0 0 1280 777 ";
    SeenOSUpdates =     (
    );
    Storefront = "143441-1,13 ab:WJ6jMoo1";
    appStoreBadgeCount = 7;
    "com.apple.appstore.WebKit2DeveloperExtrasEnabled" = 1;
    "com.apple.appstore.WebKit2ShowsToolTipOverTruncatedText" = 1;
    "com.apple.appstore.WebKit2SuppressesIncrementalRendering" = 1;
    "com.apple.appstore.WebKit2UserInterfaceDirectionPolicy" = 1;
    "primary.WebKit2DeveloperExtrasEnabled" = 1;
    "primary.WebKit2ShowsToolTipOverTruncatedText" = 1;
    "primary.WebKit2SuppressesIncrementalRendering" = 1;
}
$
```

Comment: Thats odd. My output has an   `  availableUpdates =     (); ` block. Only thing I can think of at this moment is create a new user and see if it still shows the updates? Other than that, a reinstall of Sierra if you've tried everything I've provided. But I'd delete the apps and reinstall first.

Comment: Created a dummy user and switched to that account, still showed 7 updates even though I did not sign into iCloud.

Comment: I believe this is because the apps themselves are linked to an iCloud ID and you didn't need to actually log in because of that. This is to ensure the apps are legitimate, what iCloud account it was downloaded with, etc. Has to do with receipt files on your system.

Comment: So what do I do?

Comment: If you don't care, don't worry about it. I'd delete apps I know came from the app store and reinstall. If I see a number adjustment I'd finish that. If not, I'd reinstall. Clean installs are always nice and fresh. However I have what I believe a fix to the number but not to possibly un-updated apps if there really is any. It'll be in my answer.

Comment: The accepted answer in this question (which has been closed as a duplicate of this one) is the solution, and much simpler: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258979/mac-app-store-shows-update-count-but-section-is-collapsed-empty/259001#259001

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The App Store was having problems since yesterday afternoon.
It was not your fault, the problem was on their end.
But it is back now.

Comment: I also believe this is a server overload issue where the update catalog being served to the Mac clients causes wrong calculations. Nothing has changed on dozens of Macs we manage that had this issue other than time passing and this issue has cleared up across the board now.

Answer (score 24):

I would try the following command in the terminal to download and install updates available for your mac. All commands below require administrator privileges and will prompt for your password which is NOT relayed to the screen. You will not see the caret move at all as you type it in or be replaced by "*" per character of your password. This is normal.

```
sudo softwareupdate -ia
```

This downloads and installs all available updates.

If perhaps you have configured a different App Store catalog (Usually done in businesses) you can run the following command first and then the above command. You can run it anyway to restore the catalog to defaults if you're not sure.

Reset default catalog for App Store:

```
sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog
```

For business Macs that need to restore the catalog back to the business's you can do that with the following command:

```
sudo softwareupdate --set-catalog <URL GOES HERE WITHOUT BRACKETS>
```

The first command I stated should download and install all updates but sometimes bugs happen and things don't work. Another attempt to solve the issue could be the following command first.

Reset all ignored updates:

```
sudo softwareupdate --reset-ignored -ai
```

More edits! Lets try seeing what the app store thinks is needing an update with this command:

```
defaults read com.apple.appstore
```

Last possible option I can think off is to write that no updates are available. If there are updates available this won't fix that, but it'll change the updates available number.

```
defaults write com.apple.appstore appStoreBadgeCount 0
```

This may change the badge count.

Sometimes nothing works, and a reinstall may be the best option. Steps below.

**Don't forget to backup your data!**

1. Download MacOS Sierra from the app store.
2. Reinstall by opening it and running it

**OR FOR CLEAN WIPE READ ON**

1. Wipe a USB Drive or Partition it with 6GB minimum named Untitled
2. Run the following command after downloading Sierra to create a bootable USB.

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app
   ```

   This may take a bit of time to copy onto the USB.
3. Now, boot into recovery mode by holding down alt/option directly after starting up your mac.
4. Here you will be presented with the USB option (Don't forget to plug keep it plugged in or it won't show up) **NOTE** If a firmware Password was set, you will be required to put it in to boot it up and choose a disk to boot from!
5. Booting up to the USB will be like recovery mode and you can wipe your Mac's HD/SSD and reinstall a fresh clean copy of OS Sierra.

**Don't forget to backup your data!**

Reinstalling via alt/option + command + r into the internet recovery (If available on your mac model) will revert and download and old OS that it came with out of Apple's Facility then to Sierra, so a bootable USB is a good option and you can keep it there for another use.

Comment: I only found 1 update with softwareupdate -l

Comment: More than likely it was the newest iTunes update just released a few hours ago. Which in that case didn't solve your problem. I'm getting an SSL error for those photos preventing me from seeing them. Today was the expiration date on the certificate. Sorry about that.

Comment: I noticed that you said -l for list. Can you do a sudo softwareupdate --reset-ignored and then -ia which installs all.

Comment: Why sudo? it works fine without.

Comment: It only found iTunes. It installed the update, and now the bubble is back to 7.

Comment: What mac OS are you running?

Comment: macOS Sierra 10.12.1

Comment: If you know what the apps are that are requesting to be updated, try deleting them and reinstall them. Some less drastic measures may be available but I need to locate the command to allow the App Store Developer menu item to appear. From there we can try and clear the cache. Another is System Preferences > App Store > Check updates. Another is from the App Store menu > Store > Check unfinished downloads. My final though is this is an update from another Mac on your account which is being requested for. In the App Store Preferences you'll see a "Automatically download apps on other Macs".

Comment: Sorry just noticed the "Why sudo?" And because the command does actually require administrator privileges because you're installing software. But even if it doesn't it makes the process of ruling out that you can't even update because of a standard user restriction.

Comment: Don't know the apps, and I don't believe I have more than seven apps on my computer! Also, no other Macs use my account, and I am my computer's admin.

Comment: Can you run a command defaults read com.apple.appstore and copy the output and put it in your question for me? lets see what these updates are. The debug/developer menu option isn't working or I've got the wrong one for sierra.

Comment: ok done, edited

Comment: I ran that command, it did not produce any error, but it did nothing.

Comment: I did a defaults read com.apple.appstore and it produced an output stating 0. Try a reboot. I changed it from 2 to 0. I have two currently available.

Comment: Rebooted, nothing happened. I don't know what's going on!

Comment: After rebooting, I ran `$ defaults read com.apple.appstore appStoreBadgeCount` and got 7. I reused the command in your answer, and then read the badge count again and got 0. The icon did not change however. EDIT: After rebooting again, the badge count is back to 7.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm out of ideas aside from reinstall apps and then OS if it's annoying and can't get it to zero. You sure your apps are all located strictly in the /Applications folder and not a local drive/USB?

Comment: How would I reinstall my OS? Redownload the Sierra installer app?

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your help @Jahhein, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem @OldBunny2800 however I'm sorry we couldn't solve it without a reinstall. I tried everything I could think of. Thank you for still accepting the answer. :)

Comment: Why wouldn't I? You've been helping me, a complete stranger, for no compensation for the past two hours straight. I would give you a bounty if I could! :)

Comment: This discussion should probably move to chat instead of using Comments.

Answer (score 10):

Updating from the purchased tab on the app store fixed the problem.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me - there were a number of items showing up with "update" beside them in the Purchased tab, but not showing up in the Updates tab.

Comment: at my appstore it says: you have not purchased any apps

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences and search for Updates, activate Auto Update and the Updates will be downloaded -> automatically.

[image]

I still don't see the available updates, but they have been updated and installed in the background. And since I guess, that this is just a temporary bug (it can't be coincidence, that thousands of users have the same issue simultaneously...) , this should work as work around.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I found was to go into cache and delete two folders called `com.apple.appstore`

> 1. Go to Finder and press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>;
> 2. Locate `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore` and delete `com.apple.appstore` which are cache files;
> 3. Then press again those commands and go `/private/var/folders`, open each folder and each subfolder (probably `C` subfolder) until you find `com.apple.appstore` and delete this folder;
> 4. Restart your Mac.

original answer found at: [How to fix / Reset App Store app on Mac OSX - El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245406/how-to-fix-reset-app-store-app-on-mac-osx-el-capitan)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that, when that happens, going to the "Purchases" tab will usually reveal that you've been logged out of the store somehow, and it will tell you you need to login again.  Once you've done that, you'll be able to download updates.

Answer (score 0):

Sign Out and Sign in again, and then `Check for Unfinished Download` solve the issue for me

Sign Out:

In the app store menu, click `Store` -> `Sign Out`

Sign In:

In the app store menu, click `Store` -> `Sign In`

Check for unfinished download:

In the app store menu, click `Store` -> `Check for Unfinished Download`