# App Store: You have not yet purchased any apps

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode

This morning I had the same Issue as in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258973/ghost-updates-on-mac). I had 7 Updates, but the "Updates" tab was empty. The "solution" seemed to be updating on the "Purchased" tab.

But my tab says, that I haven't purchased any apps yet.

[image]

I am logged in....

[image]

I moved from Germany to America. But I have downloaded several Updates for Xcode in Germany, as well as in America.

I have changed my "Country and Region" to the States. And *I just have tried to change it back*. The tab stays empty.

I want to update to Xcode 8.1

Now I'm downloading Xcode as if it would be a complete new app. It asked me to "get" instead of "update" Xcode...

Even tho I have it installed.

[image]

I have tried to switch back to the German Store by changing back my "Country and Region". And I have restarted my MacBook 100 times. Also, I only use this one AppID.

First Xcode download was in Germany a year ago. But update to macOS Sierra, what also brought me Xcode 8 was with this Account and with the US App Store... So it should not be a matter of Country/Region...

PS: The updates issue is gone since I have activated Auto Update.. I have no pending updates anymore.

[image]

But Xcode is still in Version 8.0 and I'm able to "download" (get) Xcode 8.1 from the store.

Comment: I CAN SEE YOUR APPLE ID ACCOUNT THROUGH THE RED MARKER.

Comment: @Bradman175 updated. thanks for the hint mate

Comment: (I've seen this happen in many situations...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Store is having problems since yesterday afternoon.
It is not your fault, it is a problem on their end.
So we just have to wait it out.

Comment: The App Store is back now.

Comment: well. i have finished downloading the "new app xcode"... but still my purchased tab says I havent downloaded anything. even THO i just said: I have finished downloading xcode (with "get")

Comment: and yes, i have restarted my macbook

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  I found an answer that got me some help:
"there is a commandline app called softwareupdate that you have to run as root.

sudo softwareupdate --list for example will give you the list of apps that are set to update. You can then run sudo softwareupdate --install {app-name}

This won't let you install a new application that you haven't already downloaded though.

shareedit
answered Nov 20 '12 at 20:08

Mark Cohen
63646"
Using Mark Cohen's suggestion, I updated iTunes by command line and today my App Store App is up to date.

Comment: I ran softwareupdate at terminal, but it only installed itunes and sierra update. not the xcode one ...