# iMovie 10.1.9 fresh download/update resets to 10.5 MB every time

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, mojave, imovie

Device Specs: MacBook Pro with Retina display, Early 2015
8 GB RAM, i5 processor

I just recently upgraded to macOS Mojave with a clean installation through the recovery mode and started downloading already purchased apps like pages, keynote, garage band and so on. All other apps got downloaded just fine except iMovie. The download progresses to 20 Mb and immediately resets to 10.5 MB and the cycle continues, and after a while the download self terminates with no message.

I tried clearing Appstore cache : [How to fix / Reset App Store app on Mac OSX - El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245406/how-to-fix-reset-app-store-app-on-mac-osx-el-capitan)

And since, iMovie was so important for me, I even reinstalled the OS (clean again) and tried downloading iMovie but it was to no avail.

P.S: I do have enough space in my volume.

Edit: I reverted back to OSX Yosemite, through the recovery mode, downloaded the compatible version of iMovie there (10.1.1) (latest version isn't compatible with Yosemite) upgraded to Mojave and tried updating iMovie to 10.1.9, however, the problem still persists. Yet, I do have the old version of iMovie which works for me. I don't know if the problem is compatibility with my Mac or something else.

[image]
[image]

Comment: and you are trying to download it from here https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imovie/id408981434?mt=12  which is 2.7 GB file

Comment: Yes, from the Mac App Store.

Comment: and you are sure there is no problem with your Internet connection/data allowance ...

Comment: Nope, as I mentioned earlier, all other apps download just fine

Comment: There is the potential that it's being cached somewhere outside your control - ISP etc & each time you re-fetch you are getting the same badly-cached copy. [Often you can get around this by using a different browser... but not for App Store of course] Try powering off your Mac & network, router etc overnight & try again in the morning.

Comment: Have you tried exit the appstore then click on the unfinished gray icon to continue download?