# How to fix the App Store after upgrading to macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, catalina

Cannot open the App Store, after upgrading to macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

Things I have tried:

- Reinstalled macOS Catalina.
- Clearing cache and removing all the related folders as given at : [How to fix / Reset App Store app on Mac OSX - El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245406/how-to-fix-reset-app-store-app-on-mac-osx-el-capitan)

Comment: We’ve had some people report the same issue. Might you have an update?

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is delete the App Store key chain entry in Finder, Application, Utilities, Keychain Access and the search for appstore. Delete just that one. (MacOS Catalina)

Comment: There is no such entry in keychain, may be I have already deleted it. But still the problem remains.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to delete all the temporary files and start in safe mode to open the App Store. If the problem persist I would try to reinstall Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

After trying every other step, including reinstalling the catalina os from recovery mode

Only this worked for me

`keychainaccess -> preferences-> clicking on "reset my Default key chain" -> reboot machine` worked  as stated [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251065439)

**Note: you will loose all the saved passwords**

Comment: Seems a bit drastic. Anyone tried opening the App Store in a brand new user account?

Comment: I'm in IT and tried every other possible method to get the App Store working again after updating to Catalina (could not update/download/buy apps: it would just sit and spin the icon). I tried pruning the Keychain manually to no avail. As soon as I reset the Keychain and rebooted, the App Store started working properly again.  Obviously there's a non-obvious entry that's hosed, but I couldn't find it.   BTW, it's really not all that drastic, unless you use your Keychain to store tons of passwords; I use LastPass for that. Resetting also leaves a backup of the old one in ~/Library/Keychains/

Answer (score 0):

Open Keychain Access and search for any entries matching "app store". I found one for the `appstored` process that once deleted, allowed the App Store to fire right up without even restarting the OS. Didn't get a screenshot unfortunately and it wasn't re-created.

If that works, you won't have to wipe out your entire default user keychain. If you have to go that route, make sure to take thorough backups of the `.keychain` or `.keychain-db` files first.